# How to add multiple values in a one row by separating in commas in mysql?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to insert values into a database by using laravel. I could insert values into the database. But I don't know how to insert multiple values into a one row by separating the values by commas.

```
id | color
------------
  1|red
  1|blue
  1|green
  2|black
  2|red
  3|pink




    This is what I expect.

    id|color
    -------------
    1 |red,blue,green
    2 |black,red
    3 |pink
```

Comment: Can you provide code from your controller?

Comment: Delimited values are a pig to deal with if all you have is mysql.

Comment: @p.salmon luckily, that doesn't appear to be the case here

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the PHP [implode](https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions.

So to turn an array into a comma separated value you do the following:

```
$data = implode(', ', ['red', 'blue', 'green']);
```

To turn it back to an array:

```
explode(', ', $data); // $data here is a string "red, blue, green"
```